# Does ListView automatically support lazyload?

Tags: android, listview, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I have images in listview, When I scroll down. It seems that it render images on the fly. is it lazyload? If yes then why lazyload library exists.

Look at the secnario.

I am rendering 25 images in listview. On the very first time it take about 5 mints to load all the images. after it takes about less then 10 second to render all the images? if listview do lazyload then why it take about 5 mints to load all the images?

Comment: Any reason for down Vote my question?

Comment: some one should write a comment before downvote. so other can know why you dislike this question. Strange people

Comment: Upvoting your question, because it is a genuine and clearly written.

Answer (score 2):

React native ListView do implement a type of Lazy loading but that is limited to rendering of row itself based on pageSize property and your Scroll position. Let say if you 100 rows, ListView won't render all rows at a given time. It will render only certain number rows and render more rows as user scrolls down. Lazy load module further enhances this by not rendering the actual row view until it is near the View port

Secondly, React Native caches images on device. So whenever remote image is being loaded it checks for local cache based upon url of image. It a cache is present it used that image instead of making new network request.

Answer (score 2):

while1 has answered your question. But I'd like to add one point. It highly depends on what you mean by lazy load.

1. Do you mean fetching the data from API as user scrolls down?
2. Or do you mean rendering the pre-fetched data as the user scrolls down?

If your answer is 1, then no. `ListView` has nothing to do with API calling. It has to be written by you. If your answer is 2 then I have found an [awesome source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/499#issuecomment-87821298) of information regarding `ListView`. I'm still posting the same answer here in case the link breaks.

In a nutshell, `ListView` handles a lot of rendering complexities implicitly.

> **Load balancing**
>
> In UITableView, when an element comes on screen, you have to
>   synchronously render it. This means that you've got less than 16ms to
>   do it. If you don't, then you drop one or multiple frames. If you are
>   rendering complex elements like newsfeed stories, it's basically
>   impossible to meet this schedule so you're doomed to drop frames.
>
> With ListView, when you reach the end of the current screen, you can
>   prepare in advance more rows to be rendered. Those rows will be
>   rendered in a different thread so won't freeze the UI thread while
>   processing. The reason why it is working is that the load is not
>   evenly spread. You don't need to render a new story on every single
>   frame, most frames are just scrolling and don't need new stories to
>   appear.
>
> ListView will also render one element at a time, so if you are
>   interacting with some element while rendering more rows, it won't
>   block until all the rows have been pre-rendered, it will only block
>   for one row.
>
> **Memory management**
>
> UITableView is very conservative memory-wise, it aggressively reuses
>   cells. This decision was made back in the iPhone 1 where memory was
>   extremely scarce. The problem with this is that reusing cell is
>   extremely error prone for the developer. You are given a dirty object,
>   from which you have no idea what mutations happened, and you need to
>   reconfigure it to look like what you want. In our iOS app, this caused
>   SOOO many bugs.
>
> The problem of reusing cell is that some cells have internal state
>   (video player running, text input, horizontal scroll position...) When
>   you reuse them, you need to be able to serialize that state and put it
>   back. This is not always possible nor easy, so you usually either
>   loose this state or it propagates on the new row and causes bugs.
>
> What we found out on React Native is that it is fast enough on iphone
>   4s to create new cells for every single row. So, we don't need to
>   impose this very hard constraint on ourself. In your screenshot, you
>   noticed that we don't remove rows after you scrolled for a while.
>   That's not entirely correct, we don't remove the virtual dom
>   representation on the React side (what you see in the chrome dev
>   tools), but we do remove those elements from the "dom" and keep their
>   reference.
>
> When they are visible again, we put them back on the dom. In case we
>   have low memory or the list is too big, we may destroy those and
>   recreate them from scratch (loosing the state as mentioned above) in
>   the future. We haven't done this performance optimization yet, but the
>   user code wouldn't be impacted.
>
> We tried to delete the iOS views aggressively but we found out that
>   doing so was actually very expensive. It was better to leave them
>   hanging than to remove them.
>
> **Change Detection**
>
> In ListView, we have a DataSource object that favors immutability. If
>   you have a list of 1000 elements to render, you want to make those
>   1000 elements immutable, meaning that you can check the previous one
>   === the next one and instantly know if something changed. This way, when anything change, the only thing you've got to do is to traverse
>   those two lists and do those very fast equality checks and know what
>   rows changed. And then update only those.
>
> **Layout**
>
> In UITableView, you've got to specify the layout of every single row
>   even when they are not being displayed on screen. So, in cases where
>   it's not a fixed size, you've got to basically render the element to
>   know its size, and pay that high cost up front. It's also very
>   annoying to do so manually.
>
> In ListView, since React Native owns the layout system, you don't need
>   to do all that painstaking manual computation yourself. When a row is
>   rendered, it'll update the size. The only downside is that the
>   scrollbar is a little funky, but I'm sure we'll be able to come up
>   with heuristics to smooth it out in the future.